# Overlapping items RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

What is the best way draw recycler's view items like overlapping.

What i already try:

- Custom ViewHolder

  ```
  layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  int leftMargin = itemLeftMargin - itemBetweenDelta;
  layoutParams.setMargins(-leftMargin, 0, 0, 0);
  itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
  ```
- Custom ItemDecorator which have left margin -some_delta_in_dp

But i get behavior not exatcly i want. Is it possible inflate close invisible items?
[image: here]

Comment: Maybe you should use `view.translate` instead of negative margin?

Comment: @PetrovDmitrii Where should i use it

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
[Pre-cache items](https://androiddevx.wordpress.com/2014/12/05/recycler-view-pre-cache-views/)